# Can not see logo in navbar

Tags: html, css

I saw question about how to add logo to navbar and I tried this

```html
<a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="C:/Users/s003/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Model/LOGO.png"></a>
```

I have already download the picture LOGO.png, and the path I input is where I put that picture. However when I open the web, instead of the LOGO, there is a broken picture icon showed in navbar. Is there anything wrong with my code? I have tried different pictures. Thanks for your help

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

         </button>
             <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="file://localhost/c:/Users/LOGO.png"></a>
             <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Science</a>
             </div>
```

Comment: *C:/Users/s003/Documents ...* - try file:/// protocol

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean file:/// protocol?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't work. I post the more code I wrote. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Nah, you got that wrong. Try to open the image in your browser (navigate to it in your explorer and drag into browser or right click open with browser) and then take the uri from your browser's address-bar.

Comment: I open it on browser. The path is C:\Users\LOGO.png I paste it into my code but still doesn't work : (

Comment: I open the picture in firefox the path showed is file:///C:/Users/LOGO.png I add it to my code but still can not show the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are viewing your webpage using localhost.(Visual studio server, or apache etc.)

Browsers do not load local file by default due to security reason.

You have to use file path relative to the html file like: ../path/to/images/
or absolute path \path\to\images

You cannot use windows path when viewing pages through server

But if still want to load local files, there are workarounds for every browsers.

For chrome: google allow file access

Example:

Lets assume this is your project path.
C:/Users/s003/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Model/

looking at your image path, LOGO image is in the root folder of project i.e Model.

if your html file is also in the same directory, you just have to use

suppose your image file is inside images folder in model folder, then you have to use

and suppose you html file is inside some view folder in model folder, then (../ to go up one directory)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand file path relative to html. As you can see my file path in my post, can you give me an example?

Comment: check this pages http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: Thanks! It works. I need to put the png into my root folder. Then it shows up